# Can "that" have a meaning of "although"?

Tags: meaning

Can *that* have a meaning of *although*?

For example,

> He was too sleepy even to be surprised **that** the people in the portraits along the corridors whispered and pointed as they passed.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Why do you think this way?

Comment: @Listenever You can read it as surprised *by the fact*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "that" is not a synonym of "although", not even in your example.

While "that" has several grammatical uses, in your sentence it is simply a conjunction connecting clauses.