# Is ‘that’ the short form of ‘of all that’?

Tags: relative-clauses, superlative-degree

Given the sentence:

> It was lucky that Harry had tea with Hagrid to look forward to, because the Potions lesson turned out to be the worst thing **that** had happened to him so far.

The relative ‘that’ after the superlative ‘the worst’ seems to have the meaning of ‘of all that.’
If yes, is ‘that’ the short form of ‘of all that’?

Comment: Why assume *that* stands for *of **all** that?* You could just as easily say *the worst thing* stands for *the worst of **all** the things*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the OP previously wondered whether [*that* means "although"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91265/can-that-have-a-meaning-of-although), so this does not come as a complete surprise.

Comment: There were certain things-that-had-happened-to-him, and this was the worst...

Comment: @ RegDwighт : Although your comment is the meanest thing that I’ve met in this website, I can have reviewed what I uploaded by your link. Thank you. By the way what’s the meaning of OP?

Comment: You are taking offense where none is intended. Quite the contrary: RegDwighт (who is, incidentally, the prime mover in the creation of a site better suited to [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners)) has a magisterial knowledge of this site, on which he draws to point out to FumbleFingers the context in which you (the **Original Poster**) should be answered.

Comment: @StoneyB: The fact is that RegDwighт’s first comment isn’t fruitful at all. So your comment neither has the reason at all. From now on you two and I HAVE TO concentrate on the question itself. That’s the way to avoid non-productive worthless comments. And there it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may certainly **rewrite** the phrase in different ways. For instance:

> “the worst thing **that**” **⇨**   “the worst thing **of all that**”
>   “the worst thing **that**” **⇨**   “the worst **of all things that**”
>   “**the** worst thing that” **⇨**   “**of all things the** worst thing that”.

But none of these implies that the bolded form on the left is a “short” form of that on the right.

> “**that**” **≠** “**of all that**”
>   “**that**” **≠** “**of all things that**”
>   “**the**”   **≠** “**of all things the**”.

Neither *of all* nor *of all things* is present-but-omitted in *that* or in *the*.  Neither is present-but-omitted in ***any*** of the words. The **idea** of *of all (things)* is ‘present’, not literally but by inference, for if something is “worse”, it must be worse than *something* to which it is compared, and if something is “worst” it must be worst of *all things* to which it is compared.

If you like, you may say that the idea of *of all (things)* is ‘made present’ in the ***-st*** ending on *most*; and that will be quite a useful notion, since it embraces not merely *worst* but also *best* and *loudest* and *funniest* as well—any superlative adjective, whether expressed with *-st* or with *most*. But when you get to that point it becomes clear that even the *idea* of *of all* is not “omitted”; it is merely not-expressed-in-those-words.

When you put *of all* or *of all things* into the sentence, or perform any other such transformation, you are not restoring something missing; you’re pointing an arrow at something you think is important, or ornamenting the sentence to make it more musical.

But all that is merely what FumbleFingers told you in the very first comment. And *that*, as tchrist told you (much more efficiently), “is simply the relative.”

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such special meaning here.  It is simply the relative.  You are reading too much into it.  It never means what you seem to be thinking it means.